# How do I deploy an app with javafx keyboard?

Tags: maven, deployment, javafx, jvm-arguments

I've build an app using javafx. It was developed to use with a touch screen. In my vm I specified the following arguments:

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true -Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true -Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx
```

With this arguments when I select some kind of data input the javafx digital keyboard pops up.

Now I want to deploy the app with the same arguments using maven. How can I do that?

I've tried with the following pom definitions (suggested by ItachiUchia) but with no luck:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.app_name.Main</mainClass>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true</argument>
                        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true</argument>
                        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx</argument>
                    </jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the JVM args using the [`jvmArgs`](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/native-mojo.html#jvmArgs) in the configuration of the javafx-maven-plugin. A simple example :

```
<configuration>
    <jvmArgs>
        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx</argument>
    </jvmArgs>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but without luck. I've updated the question to reflect your answer. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Can you try `<jvmArg>-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true</jvmArg>` instead of `<argument>-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true</argument>`

Comment: Are you creating a native build?

Comment: No. I'm using "mvn clean jfx:jar".

Comment: I have never tried myself, but `jvmArgs` seems to be applicable for only [`jfx:native`](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/native-mojo.html) and not for [`jfx:jar`](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/jar-mojo.html)